# Can a Markov process be ergodic but not stationary?

Tags: markov-process, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes, statistical-mechanics

Given a continuous-time continuous-state Markov process:

> A Markov process $X$ is ergodic if there exists a unique invariant
>   probability distribution $\mu$ and, for any state $x$, the transition probabilities $P(X_t ∈ ·|X_0 = x)$ converge to that distribution in total variation.

and

> A Markov process $X$ having invariant (probability) measure $\mu$ is a stationary process if $X_0 \sim \mu$.

I am confused because I thought that ergodicity implied stationarity, but according to these two definitions, it seems that the process $X$ with $X_0 = x$, a point mass, would still be ergodic but not stationary.

*edit*: I am interested in whether Birkhoff ergodic theorem applies to $X$ with $X_0=x$.

Comment: OK, and what is the question?

Comment: my question is can a Markov process be ergodic but not stationary? Is there a conflict in this definition of ergodicity?

Comment: Note that it is a pretty bad definition of ergodicity (although it is sufficient for most "truly" stochastic processes). That said, yes, ergodicity does not imply stationarity, nor does stationarity implies ergodicity. But you can still use Birkhoff's ergodic theorem anyways (with the ergodic measure $\mu$).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I based my question on this other one where the consensus seemed to be that ergodicity does imply stationarity: [does ergodicity imply stationarity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593746/does-ergodicity-imply-stationarity)